# The area of a region around a curve

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, area

If we are given a simple closed curve with length $L$ in the plane, and we have a fixed number $r$ such that for each point $x$ on the curve there is a related disc $D(x,r)$ with radius $r$, how can we estimate the area of the region formed by all such discs from above?

Comment: An easy, and in many cases accurate approximation would of course just be L * 2r.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Because I know in many cases L*2r is the exact formula, but I want to know a universal estimate and I don't know how to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: Well I think that the more uniform the curvature the closer this estimate should be. Now that I think about it this could probably be done accurately by integrating over the curve based upon the radii of curvature. Let me think on this and I may post an answer. Out of curiosity how is the curve represented?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to think about it. Well, there is no specific curve in mind and I am just curious about such a problem because it looks like a classical problem but I cannot find its answer easily.

Comment: For regular enough closed curve and sufficiently small $r$, the $2rL$ is not an approximation, it is exact! This is a special case of the [Weyl's tube formula](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/03/intrinsic_volumes_for_riemanni.html). I believe the most comprehensive reference on this subject is Alfred Gray's book [Tubes](http://www.amazon.com/Tubes-Progress-Mathematics-Alfred-Gray/dp/3764369078).

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for your information, it's very useful for me, I will take a look at it.

Comment: This [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/604176/59379) to a similar question is probably what you want. Pay attention to the Jacobian of parametrization in this answer. The most important observation is the difference between the Jacobian and 1 is an odd function in the distance from the curve. That's what ultimately make $2rL$ exact.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following approach it seems that the general answer is indeed just $2rL$.

[image: curve diagram]

Assuming the curve has no sharp points, this problem is equivalent to the sum line segments at each point $x_0$ along the curve, each centered at $x_0$, perpendicular to the curve at that point, and of length $2r$. Observing the diagram above, it can be seen that for any radius of the circle not perpendicular to the curve, such as the green one, there must be another point, $x_1$, along the curve closer to its position on the circumference. This is true because obviously any close point along tangential line (the dark red line) in the correct direction will be closer, and since the curve is continuous, in moving closer toward $x_0$ you can get a point $x_1$ arbitrarily close to the tangential line. Another way of thinking about it is to think about $x_1$ as infinitesimally farther down the curve than $x_0$, and since the measure is infinitesimal, the slope is unchanging and it can be thought of as moving down the tangent line.

[image: curve diagram]

If we let $R_t$ represent the radius of curvature at a distance $t$ along the curve, we can then do the following.

$$
\begin{align}
A & = \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{2\pi} \left( \pi(R_t+r)^2 - \pi(R_t-r)^2 \right)\\[2ex]
A & = \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{2\pi} \left(4\pi rR_t\right)\\[2ex]
A & = 2rR_t \:\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}$$

and since $\mathrm{d}\theta = \mathrm{d}t / R_t$

$$
A = 2r \:\mathrm{d}t\\[2ex]
\int_0^L 2r \:\mathrm{d}t = 2rL
$$

I realize that this does **not** hold if the curve has any sharp points. However for any sharp points you can manually add the uncounted circle section ($\frac{\theta}{2}r^2$) as well as subtracting all the overlapping area ($r^2\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})$) for a final answer of

$$2rL + r^2 \sum_{\theta_i} \frac{\theta_i}{2} - \cot\left(\frac{\theta_i}{2}\right) $$

where $\theta_i$ is the angle change at the $i^{th}$ sharp point.
The only circumstance I can see in which this would not work is if two points on the curve ever came closer than 2r away from each other and you were counting some area twice.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is a very nice situation, but we don't have any restriction about $r$ and $L$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. The diagram given was just a small (technically infinitesimal) section of a potentially more complicated curve with varying curvature.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It looks like I misunderstood you. I will rethink about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this essentially answers the following question: if for any point $x$ we have a related "normal" segment with length $2r$ whose midpoint is $x$, then the resulting region $R$ has the area less than $2rL$. But I am not sure if my question is equivalent to this one. In other words, is every disc $D(x,r)$ contained in $R$? This may not be true if $r$ is large (comparing to your $R_t$). I believe this ares can still be controlled from above by $2rL$, but I don't know how to prove it strictly.

Comment: You are correct in that that is what my answer shows, which I do believe is equivalent to your question. I'm sorry if I made the jump without explaining myself and I'll edit my post in a minute.

Comment: Thanks for your new answer. But do we still have some estimate when the sharp points exist?

Comment: @DanqingHe It is still probably at least fairly close as there is some uncounted area as well as some doubly counted area at any sharp point, I don't know whether or not it would still be a perfect measure though (or even if its an over or underestimate). It may actually still be correct, though I may not be able to formulate it rigorously I'm thinking that maybe if you think about the limit of a curve as it gets closer and closer to a sharp point it would get closer and closer to the 2rL. I suppose if it was not a good estimate you could try calculating the discrepancies for each point.

Comment: I sketched out some stuff to basically add up the discrepancies at each sharp point and I'll update my answer with it.